# Gzip not working for javascript files only in IIS 7 integrated with Tomcat 7 using isapi_redirect.dll

Tags: tomcat, iis-7, tomcat7, gzip, isapi-redirect

I am using the tomcat connector ([isapi_redirect.dll](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html)) to integrate with IIS 7.

After enabling both static & dynamic compression at website level using IIS Manager, the `gzip` compression is not working for only `javascript` files.

After little debugging, figured out that the `Content-Type of .js request` is also strangely not `application/x-javascript` as it should have been according to the mimeMapping `applicationHost.config`, instead it is `application/javascript`.

I've already tried adding `mimeType application/javascript` to `applicationHost.config` and also in `web.config` under `httpCompression` tag. But nothing worked.

Although enabling compression at Tomcat7 level works fine (accessing the site on port 8080).

I have also tried to use a different connector - http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org but the same issue - `.js files doesn't compress`.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the mimeType of `js` files in `Tomcat7/conf/web.xml` to `application/javascript`.

```
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

Also, there is no need to enable compression at Tomcat level, as it won't work when fronted by Apache/IIS.